# How to render time function results in component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that formats the date and returns a timestamp. Currently the date is working but I cannot render the `readableTime` function in a Results component. You will see the state is setup as a condition to render the Results component which should hold the `readableTime function`. I can return text `working`, but not the function. Any help appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';

const DatetimeCell = (props) => {
    
const [showReadableTime, setShowReadableTime] = useState(false);

const readableTime = (timestamp) => {
        const time = new Date(timestamp);
        const timeOptions = {
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: 'numeric',
            hour12: true
    };
const rTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', timeOptions).format(time);
        return rTime;
}

const dateFormat = (timestamp) => {
const date = new Date(timestamp);

     return (date.getMonth() + 1) +
            "/" + date.getDate() +
            "/" + date.getFullYear();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setShowReadableTime(true);
    }, []);

    const Results = () => (
        <span> working{readableTime}</span>
    )

    const tooltipOptions = {
        text: props.text,
        tooltip: props.tooltip,
        tooltipPlacement: props.tooltipPlacement
    };

    return (
        <>
            <ReactTooltip />
                <td data-tip={dateFormat(tooltipOptions.tooltip)} data-place={tooltipOptions.tooltipPlacement || 'right'}>
                    {dateFormat(tooltipOptions.text)}
                    { showReadableTime ? <Results /> : null }
                </td>
        </>
    )
};

export default DatetimeCell;
```

Comment: You're not passing `timestamp` as a parameter to the `readableTime` function. Doesn't it throw an error?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot that. Will update code. thanks. Still does not return for some reason.

Comment: Ah now I see it. Since `readableTime` is a function, you need to call it from `Results`, with the argument. Right now you're just referencing the function.

Comment: I tried that and nothing. {readableTime(timestamp)}. Maybe I am misunderstanding. Do you have an example?

Comment: Sure. let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `readableTime` is a function that accepts `timestamp` as a parameter. Your rest of the code doesn't seem to indicate where the `timestamp` would come from, so I assume you'll pass it as a literal value when you're calling it, like so:

```
const Results = () => (
    <span> working {readableTime(1661146119165)}</span>
)
```

If by any chance you want to output the current time as default, you could update your function signature to have a default value for `timestamp`, like so:

```
const readableTime = (timestamp = Date.now()) => {...}
```

Or you could handle the missing parameter inside the function definition.

```
const readableTime = (timestamp) => {
    if (!timestamp) {
        timestamp = Date.now();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you could call the function without the `timestamp` parameter as well.

```
const Results = () => (
    <span> working {readableTime(1661146119165)}</span>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples. If I were to pass a placeholder through the Results component how would I do that to return dynamic time. I already have the constant from the API. You can see how I did it with tooltipOptions object and called the property text which is the attribute, but how do I do it with the time? Sorry, last question.

Comment: `Results` is a React component, so you always have `props`. You pass timestamp as a prop: `<Results timestamp={tooltip.timestamp} />`. And you access it within the component from props: `const Results = (props) => {return <span> working {readableTime(props.timestamp)}</span>}`